# "Connection aborted" error when using Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape price information from Carrefour website with the following code

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
    }
link = 'https://www.carrefour.es/extensor-tp-link-rango-75/366506176/p'
response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=60)
# Following lines parse response with Beautifulsoup
```

This code ends up with "Connection aborted" error. The error message is sligted different on Linux and Windows

When run on AWS (Ubuntu), it always result in error with below message

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

While run on my PC (Win10), sometimes it works correctly, sometimes error occurs with message below

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

I guess this is not caused by IP restriction or User-Agent: Although the script result in no connect, I can still visit link using my PC (Win10), with same IP and User-Agent.

Am I blocked? What's the possible reason of being blocked?